# How can I subscribe a dynamic topic in graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I have a graphql subscription in nodejs as below:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: () => { ... },
    Mutation: () => { ... },
    Subscription: {
        commentAdded: {
          subscribe: withFilter(
            () => pubsub.asyncIterator('COMMENT_ADDED'),
            (payload, variables) => {
             return payload.commentAdded.repository_name === variables.repoFullName;
            },
          ),
        }
    },
};
```

You can see the topic this subscription uses is `COMMENT_ADDED` which is a hard coded string. I am wondering whether I can create a dynamic topic name based on user request.

Something like below code. It subscribes the topic with `payload.id` as its suffix. How can I do this in apollo server?

```
subscribe: withFilter(
            (payload) => pubsub.asyncIterator('COMMENT_ADDED:'+payload.id),
            (payload, variables) => {
             return payload.commentAdded.repository_name === variables.repoFullName;
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function passed to `withFilter` is the `subscribe` function, which is what determines the value of the payload. So it cannot be passed the payload as a parameter. The function is passed four parameters, the same as any root resolver -- the root value, the field's arguments, the context and a GraphQLResolveInfo object.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to subscribe on a dynamic topic? The function with the parameters is called when there is an event need to publish rather than subscribe.

Comment: The `subscribe` function is called when a client makes the initial request. But it is called with the four parameters I described. You can use any of those parameters (like the args) to generate the topic to subscribe to. Once the topic is subscribed to, though, the only way to change it is to cancel the subscription and start a new one.

Comment: The `subscribe` function uses `withFilter` which has two functions inside. The first one doesn't have any parameters. And it is where the topic is defined. The second function has the 4 parameters you mentioned but this function is called when there is an event published to the topic.  How can I generate the topic in the second function?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that. The function has the four I've already described. You can see it in the source code [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions/blob/b55d4846465be3442d5a2036b78264c83a4215e2/src/with-filter.ts). The second function is the filter function -- you can't return an AsyncIterator inside it. The first function is the subscribe function that should return an AsyncIterator specific to your topic. In other words, the first function passed to withFilter is the same function you would write if you were not using withFilter in the first place.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I see the first root value is undefined so I thought there is no argument in the first function.